# How can I repeat some commands before each paragraph?

Tags: bibliographies, copy-paste, mla-style

I have to use [EasyBib](http://www.easybib.com/) to make my bibliography, and I've put it into my LaTeX document by copying/pasting. But I need to have a hanging indent for each item.

I've been able to get the effect I want by putting this before each item:

```
\hangindent=2.5em
\noindent
```

However, I have to write this out for every item. Is there a way to automate doing this?

Comment: `\everypar{...}` or `\parindent=0pt`?

Comment: @HenriMenke `\noindent` doesn't seem to work with that. (I'm using `\everypar{\noindent\hangindent=2.5em}` and I've tried with/without the `\hangindent`. It doesn't seem to have any effect. The hanging indent does work though.

Comment: Then try `\parindent=0pt`.

Comment: @HenriMenke That did work - I had to move the `\parindent` outside the `\everypar` If you put your comment as an Answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I would recommend to use `bibtex` or `biblatex` to manage your bibliography. Alternatively you can warp the bibliography in `\begin{thebibliogrpahy}{99}` and `\end{thebibliography} and `\bibitem` before each entry.

Comment: @Guido My assignment requires that the Bibliography be submitted using EasyBib, so unfortunately that is not an option for me.

Comment: so you cannot use `bibtex`, but you can still wrap the data obtained from EasyBib in a `thebibliography` environment

Comment: @Guido I tried your suggestion, but couldn't get hanging indents to work with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of putting `\noindent` in front of every item, it is easier to set globally

```
\parindent=0pt
```

Furthermore I recommend, that you use either LaTeX's internal [`thebibliography`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Embedded_system) environment or [`bibtex`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX).

Answer (score 7):

The indentation of the first line for all paragraphs in scope can be set by (see Menke's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173683/16967)):

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

`\hangindent` has to be repeated for each paragraph. `\everypar` helps:

```
\everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{2.5em}}
```

But caution is needed, because LaTeX uses `\everypar` quite often itself, e.g. in `\section` and friends.

An alternative is moving the paragraphs to the right by setting `\leftskip` and moving the first line to the left using a negative value for `\parindent`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[65]

\bigskip

\setlength{\hangindent}{2.5em}
\noindent
\lipsum[65]

\bigskip

\begingroup
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{2.5em}}%
  \lipsum[65-66]
  \par
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begingroup
  \par
  \setlength{\parindent}{-2.5em}
  \addtolength{\leftskip}{-\parindent}
  \lipsum[65-66]
  \par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]